# php artisan migrate ignores settings in local environment directory for database

Tags: php, database-migration, homestead, laravel-4.2

I have a weird problem with Laravel 4.2 migrations since I tried to use Homestead as my development environment. When I do a 
`php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
[PDOException]           
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'prod'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Laravel is using the database settings from my production environment, allthough Laravel has the correct environment detected:

```
$ php artisan env
Current application environment: local
```

The corresponding database.php is also in place:

```
$ cat app/config/local/database.php 
<?php

return array(

[...]    
    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'homestead',
            'username'  => 'homestead',
            'password'  => 'secret',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => true,
        ),
[...]
    ),

);
```

Has anybody an idea how to find out where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the error message your username is `prod`. So, you should use this:

```
'username'  => 'prod',
'password'  => 'your_password',
```

**Note:** Editing `database.php` is one kind of hard coding. And this file can be seen if you upload your project to `github`. I always prefer to use `.env` for database and email configuration.

Comment: I do not know and cannot find anything in the docs regarding .env file. Please note that I am talking about Laravel 4.2 (not 5.2, where your way is the way to go), where according to the docs, creating a directory with the corresponding name and override settings in this directories (See https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: If you don't understand ignore the `.env` for now. Provide your correct `username` & `password` in `database.php` as my answer.

Comment: I do understand how .env works. But this kind of configuration does not exist in Laravel 4.2. I provide the correct username and password for the database in `/app/config/local/database.php` (for my local dev environment) and in `/app/config/database.php` for my production environment. It does not make sense to change the settings in `/app/config/database.php` as this would break my production environment. The querstion here is: Why does Laravel ignore my overridings in `/app/config/local/database.php`?

Comment: Your error message in question says, your username is `prod`, your host name is `localhost` and you have a password. In the other side, in your configuration you said, your username is `homestead`, your host name is `localhost` and your password is `homestead`. I can see your username is not matched with host's username, don't know about password as it is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the values in the .env file instead of hardcoding them into database.php. Then use constants in the database.php mysql array. It will look something like this:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I would of commented first, but I don't have a strong enough rep. Sorry.

Comment: I know the .env configuration in Laravel 5.2, but not in 4.2. According to the Docs (https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) creating a directory with the name of the environment and overriding settings there is the way to go in this version or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for this answer, the issue illuminated in the comments to the question relates to the use of the .env file.  In Laravel 4.2, the simplest solution is to use a .env.local.php file in the app directory with the following format:

```html
<?php

return array(
    'APP_ENV'=>'local',
    'DB_HOST'=>'127.0.0.1',
    'DB_PORT'=>'3306',
    'DB_NAME'=>'database_name',
    'DB_USER'=>'app_user',
    'DB_PASS'=>'app_password',
);
```